# Appending to a string makes it null, C

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function which adds a character to a string, the comments in the code below explains the problem. I think I'm using the pointer wrongly.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    string hash = argv[1];    // Read from argv
    crack_password(hash);
}

void crack_password(char * hash) {
     printf("%d\n", hash); // prints correctly.
     string * password_guess; // = some functionality, hash doesn't change
     match_password(password_guess, hash);    
}

match_password(char * password_guess, char * hash) {
     printf("%d\n", hash) // prints correctly.
     char first_two_letters[2] = "";
     append(first_two_letters, hash[0]);

     printf("Hash: %s\n", hash);
     append(first_two_letters, hash[1]);
     printf("%d\n", first_two_letters); // prints first two letters of the hash.
     printf("%d\n", hash); // hash null here.
}

void append(char * s, char c) {
    int len = strlen(s);
    s[len] = c;
    s[len + 1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: `char first_two_letters[2]` declares an array of 2 bytes. Appending twice requires an array of at least 3 bytes. Try `char first_two_letters[8]`

Comment: What is `string`? Always include the complete code, especially when using types or definitions that are not standard.

Comment: Does `match_password()` not have a return type?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of first_two_letters is too small. It's always the numbers of chars you want to save +1 (for the appending '\0').
hash is stored on the stack right after first_two_letters, which means you're writing the '\0' of first_two_letters into the hash variable that's why it appears empty.

`char first_two_letters[3] = "";`

Should do the trick.